# Merging two separate tabs of excel sheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have two separate excel sheets (xlsx format),

Excel 1 - Has 2 separate tabs.

- Tab 1 has summary information linked to Tab 2 and
- Tab 2 is the data to be taken from Excel 2

Excel 2 - Has relevant info (which needs to be copied to tab 2 of excel 1)

Sample of 2 files are shared in the below link

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1inrofeT6v9P0ISEcmbswvpxMMCq5TaV0?usp=sharing

Name references of both the files are the same. Basically, I want to copy the information from Excel 2 and paste it to Excel 1 (Which has a summary sheet to provide summary information)

I tried the below code

```
# importing openpyxl module
import openpyxl as xl
  
# opening the source excel file
filename ="D:\\1. Python Extracts\\KA-AVRB-Feb22-4.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
  
# opening the destination excel file 
filename1 ="D:\\2. Summary shees\\KA-AVRB-Feb22-4.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[1]
  
# calculate total number of rows and columns in source excel file

mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column
  
# copying the cell values from source excel file to destination excel file

for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        # reading cell value from source excel file
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
  
        # writing the read value to destination excel file
        ws2.cell(row = i+1, column = j).value = c.value
  
# saving the destination excel file
wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

The above code works with individual files. However, I have 2 sets of 140 excel files (i.e 140 excel summary sheets and 140 excel sheets having data), where I need to copy data from one file and paste it to another as explained above.

I understand I can try to place a for loop for the same, but after much trial, I'm unable to achieve the same.

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: openpyxl does not support merging of two sheets from two different workbooks if that is what you mean.

Comment: @BijayRegmi Not merging ,. Simple task of copy and paste. I have achieved that when I do one file at a time,. Not able to perform a loop for multiple files at a time.

Comment: Please also write the error or wrong output you are getting on doing this.

Comment: @Zircoz if you mean an error on running the above code, there are no errors. I'm able to achieve copy and past, but only one file name at a time, but not for multiple files.

Comment: you might want to use something like RPA tools. TagUI is free to use for Python (https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI)

Answer (score 2):

Keeping source files in a subfolder named sourceFiles, and summaries in a subfolder named summary, we can iterate over all source files and run your function over them to make the summaries.

```py
import os
# importing openpyxl module
import openpyxl as xl

for _, _, file in os.walk("/sourceFiles", topdown=False):
    makeSummary(file)

def makeSummary(filename):
    # opening the source excel file
    #filename ="D:\\1. Python Extracts\\KA-AVRB-Feb22-4.xlsx"

    wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
    ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
  
    # opening the destination excel file 
    filename1 =".\summary\"+filename
    wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
    ws2 = wb2.worksheets[1]
  
    # calculate total number of rows and columns in source excel file

    mr = ws1.max_row
    mc = ws1.max_column
  
    # copying the cell values from source excel file to destination excel file

    for i in range (1, mr + 1):
        for j in range (1, mc + 1):
            # reading cell value from source excel file
            c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
  
            # writing the read value to destination excel file
            ws2.cell(row = i+1, column = j).value = c.value
  
    # saving the destination excel file
    wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

PS: I haven't run this code on your files and I am uncertain about slashes now since I used this ages ago. Hence, please try to debug the path if this iteration doesn't work. To see how python's `walk()` works, refer [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm).